# Should I write my C++ code as a static or dynamic library if I want to test it?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, googletest

I'm working on a C++ project in Visual Studio and wanted to test it using Google Test.

In order to do so, I built a solution which includes three projects:

1. Code project as a console application.
2. Google Test as a static library.
3. Tests project as a console application.

I wrote the code in the code project and a test in the test project.

When I tried building the solution, I got a lnk2019 error which stopped happening when I moved the classes to the tests project (but that's not where I want them to be).

I read that the best way to do so is by writing the classes as a library so I'll be able to use them in both (code and tests) projects.

Should I do that as a static library or as a DLL (and why)?

Other solutions are welcomed as well.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you write the code as a static or dynamic library. If you could only test one of them, that would be very bad for everyone that needed to write the other type! Make the choice of a static or dynamic library according to what you actually need/want for your project's design. Then, figure out how to solve [the linker error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z.aspx) so you can test.

Comment: Create a static lib, then create a 2nd project the builds a dynamic lib from the 1st project. Now you have both.

Comment: Test the version you intend to deliver.  If you are going to deliver dynamic libraries then test with dynamic libraries.

Comment: If you make a static lib; you will need to supply the libraries with the production code project provided all the paths are set and resolved when you build out the application. If you make a dynamic lib, they will need the *.dll and where it is located. Usually the location of these types of libraries are set up within the IDE for linking and building or through the use of an installer application.

Comment: Thanks! Currently tried the static library, my example test seems to work fine and no more lnk2019 error.

Comment: Thanks for the timely accept!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key thing to understand here: you are getting things backwards.

You do **not** make this decision in order to get to "easier" testing. You first and foremost have to understand the "production requirements" towards your delivery. You create a static library, if that is the best for shipping your product. If not, you create a dynamic library.

For testing, you either *deal* with the chosen "delivery format"; or you think about a simple way that allows you to build a different thing for testing (although that is discouraged, as you want to test your product, nothing else).

Don't get me wrong: it is important to design for testing; but the decision you are asking for should be driven by your production requirements!

In other words: the "form factor" of your product should depend on product requirements, it should not be determined by your test setup.

Comment: Thanks for helping me re-organize my thoughts.

Comment: Thanks @GhostCat!